# Python : pass variable to url while doing request

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm using the following  to call a url , which I need to pass  year/month/day as variable while calling it 
so the final url structure be like

> ```
> http://mywebiste.com/downloading/main/2016/03/28/'
> ```

here is my code ,

```
import pycurl
import os, sys, re, shutil
import datetime
import time
import requests
import datetime
import logging
import httplib

#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
day =  now.day

url = 'http://mywebiste.com/downloading/main/%s/%s/%s/'
r = requests.get(url,timeout=10)
r.text
r.status_code
r.connection.close()
```

Comment: Thus far you don't even *attempt* to put the values into the placeholders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
url = 'http://mywebiste.com/downloading/main/%s/%s/%s/' % (year, month, day)
```

Little more explaining: for each string you want use with variables with `%` way you need to use string as `my_string = 'my value is: %s' % value`, where value is your variable.

Comment: you might have to str() any numeric values in the tuple as the pattern expects 3 strings.  I don't recall what year month and day are in that structure of the top of my head.

Comment: Actually, according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)(that table, `'s'`) each passed object is converted automatically with `str()`. However if not sure, better use than sorry. :)